# Can't install Elementary OS [screen glitch]

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, elementary-os

So, everytime I get past the "Try and Install Elemmentary OS" page my screen glitches and nothing further happens. I matched checksum, reflashed the live-usb multiple times, tried installing elementary on my old laptop using the same usb-drive, and it Installs!! but doesn't install on my main desktop. What do I do? How do I install it?

specs of desktop (on which it does not install):
cpu: i5 10400,
motherboard: gigabyte h410m h,
gpu: nvidia gtx 1650,

specs of laptop (on which it installs):
cpu: intel celeron b800,
gpu: integrated